# Ckeditor in yii Insert only data in DB and not html tags

Tags: php, yii, ckeditor

Using `Ckeditor` extension in `Yii` I want to insert data only in Database,

Once `Ckeditor` Showing its fine but insert data in Db with `<p>` tag itself.

For example,

```
<p>Sample</p>
```

Insert in Db

But I want `Sample` only and not the `<p>` and `<br>` tags etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PHP strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for this and strip out html tags in your controller (note that this will remove all the html tags), for example:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new MyModel;

        if(isset($_POST['MyModel']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['MyModel'];
            $model->mytext = strip_tags($model->mytext);//strip html tags
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to remove the default `<p>` that appears, you can do the following :

```
var config = {
...
enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
....
};
```

Here are the complete steps to follow:

- [Download](http://ckeditor.com/download) Ckeditor.
- Extract the downloaded file and place the ckeditor folder outside protected folder. Your folder structure should be like: `webapp/ckeditor`
- Add the code in your view:

  ```
  <?php
  $js=Yii::app()->getClientScript();
  $js->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
  $js->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js');

  $js->registerScript(
    'js2',
    '
      var config = {
      toolbar:
      [
       ["Bold", "Italic","Underline", "-", "NumberedList", "BulletedList", "-" ],  
       ["UIColor"],["TextColor"],["Undo","Redo","Link"],
       ["JustifyLeft","JustifyCenter","JustifyRight","JustifyBlock"],
       ["NumberedList","BulletedList","FontSize","Font","Preview"]
      ],
      enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
      shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
      height:150,
      width:580
      };
      $("#State_state").ckeditor(config);
    ',
    CClientScript::POS_LOAD
  );
  ?>
  <div class="form">

  <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id'=>'state-form',
      'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
  )); 
  ?>

  <div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'state'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'state'); ?>
  </div>


  <div class="row buttons">
      <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
  </div>

  <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
  </div>
  ```